# Removing double slashes from Sys.getenv()

Tags: r, environment-variables, stringr

In R, I can see an environment variable has the correct file path.

```
> Sys.getenv()
...
TEMP                      C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\1
TMP                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\1
USERPROFILE               C:\Users\username
...
```

But when I retrieve USERPROFILE directly, double slashes appear.

```
> Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")
[1] "C:\\Users\\username
```

Why is R inserting an extra slash into the string? I'm writing a package that needs to be cross-platform compatible. Besides `grep` or `stringr`, is there a better solution to remove the double slash and still account for the possibility of a network file location (which would have double slashes at the beginning)?

Comment: What you call "extra slash" is just meant to be an escape character. See how, for instance, a string containing quotes (say `x<-'a "quote"';x`) is printed. In your example, see what `cat(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"))` produces (the "extra slash" disappears). Therefore, no reason to worry.

Comment: look at `nchar("\\")`

Comment: Side note: if you're building a path, use `file.path` instead of guessing whether forward or backslashes apply on the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nicola's comment is correct. The "extra slash" is just in the *printed* output. It does not really exist.